# Why is the question 13264 labeled as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/13264/why-didnt-the-holy-prophet-choose-any-leader-for-islamic-society is marked as duplicate by some of the users and mods. It's even said that the answer to this question is found in https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11621/original-successor-of-muhammed.

[image]

The point is that, the first mentioned question is a question of "Why" and the answer to latter is about the fact that the prophet (PBUH) didn't choose a successor and not about "Why" he didn't do it!

So the questions which may strike the minds are that:

1. Why is it marked as duplicate and shouldn't it be opened?
2. Did the users who marked it as duplicate really pay attention to the main aim of the questioner? (none of the understood this point! )

Comment: The question in question is **extremely vague and low quality**. There's no reason to reopen it unless some kind soul edits the question into shape.

Comment: @JonEricson It is every thing but not "duplicate", is it?

Comment: Who knows? The question doesn't seem like it's asking what it says on the surface. Isn't this the very core of the division between Shia and Sunni? Sounds like the question is a prybar intended to stir up needless controversy.

Comment: @JonEricson None of what you mentioned is a good reason for marking the question with **duplicate** label. For example they could flag it for being very low quality or sth else. However, 5 people made such a decision, this is even making me more suprised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is not duplicate in my opinion. The other question asks about the original successor of the prophet (which is probably more controversial). This question asks about Why the prophet did not choose a successor which is a valid question in my opinion.

The accepted answer from the other duplicate questions says (quoting)

> 1. **Muhammad did not nominate a political successor** or caliph but Ali was
>      conferred the spiritual superiority over others

So this question is more of continuation on the first question and asking for more. GoldPsudoe answer above says, it need more details. I don't think it needs unnecessary detail. It is a known fact among Sunni at least, that he did not appoint a successor (as a successor). He did ask Abu Bakr once to lead prayers and followed behind him. I am not sure if that can be counted as successor.

The question is valid, a good one and not duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for involving the discussion. [another question of mine](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/14741/how-could-the-prophet-pbuh-not-assign-a-successor-after-his-death-sunni-brot) is also onhold!

Comment: yep noticed that!

Answer (score 3):

Four people thought it was a duplicate.  Five if you count the first comment from Farhan.

It's been closed for almost a month, and the questioner made zero attempt to elaborate on his question to explain *what* he was looking for in an answer that wasn't already covered by the other question.  In fact, the *only* attempt the questioner (or *anyone*, for that matter) made to defend his question was saying "[it is different guestion and need different answer!](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/13264/why-didnt-the-holy-prophet-choose-any-leader-for-islamic-society#comment25452_13264)"  Which is far from a compelling argument.

Even if it wasn't an exact duplicate, the question shows absolutely zero research effort and is extremely low quality (it pretty much has no question body, just a repeat of the title), so there really is no compelling reason to reopen it.  Frankly, the fact that it even *has* upvotes at all makes me suspicious of voting fraud.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head, It is not an exact duplicate! but I do agree that it is low quality. The problem is that five people ( as we know!) has marked it wrongly. They'd better tell the questioner about the quality not mislead him.

Comment: @MohammadHossein The onus is on the questioner to demonstrate, to convince the *community*, that his question is *not* a duplicate.  Obviously, five people felt that he failed in that; that's a problem with the *question*, not with the voters.

Comment: Im not writing for vindication of the questioner. I believe that both sides have to be careful. Even the voters have a heavier duty. We have to judge the posts correctly and honestly for the sake of Allah.